# DecimalFormat pattern problem

Tags: java, android

I try to format a number using NumberFormatter in Android. I use the code bellow and it works perfectly:

```
 NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
 String myFormattedString = formatter.format(123456);
```

But, when i use a pattern with space, like that: `new DecimalFormat("###,# ##");` it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. I've read documentation about NumberFormatter and DecimalFormatter and found nothing about spaces in patterns. Can anyone explane me why can't i use spaces or how to add them as allowed characters. 
 Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can not put spaces in the middle of a number: it is not a valid format.

If you look at [the JavaDoc of `DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), you'll see this:

> ```
> Prefix:
>         any Unicode characters except \uFFFE, \uFFFF, and special characters  
> Suffix:  
>         any Unicode characters except \uFFFE, \uFFFF, and special characters  
> Number:  
>         Integer Exponentopt  
>         Integer . Fraction Exponentopt
> ```

Without copying the entire doc, none of the components of the `Number` pattern accept spaces, so trying to fit a space in the middle will not work. You can only use spaces in the prefix or suffix.

Answer (score 3):

In a regular JDK this does not throw an exception - it just formats the number as `123,456`.

It is not clear what is the space in your example. You have a couple of options for a symbol's role:

- decimal separator
- group separator
- exponent separator
- monetary decimal separator

You can set each of these with:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
formatter.setSymbols(symbols);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved my goal by making my own formatter using standart formatter and finding prohibited symbols using exeptions. Hope it will be useful for someone else.

```
public static String getFormattedNumberWithPattern(String aPattern,
            float aNumber) {
        String lFormattedNumber = null;
        String lOriginalPattern = aPattern;
        try {
            Hashtable<Integer, String> lIlligalChars = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
            // analyze illegal characters
            for (int i = aPattern.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char[] lAux = new char[1];
                aPattern.getChars(i, i + 1, lAux, 0);
                try {
                    // if character is illegal, it throws an exception
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    NumberFormat lNumberFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#"
                            + lAux[0] + "#");
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // add illegal chars and indexes to dictionary
                    lIlligalChars.put(new Integer(i), String.valueOf(lAux[0]));}}
            Enumeration<String> lChars = lIlligalChars.elements();
            while (lChars.hasMoreElements()) {
                String lIllegalChar = lChars.nextElement();
                // remove illegal chars from pattern
                aPattern = removeChar(aPattern, lIllegalChar.charAt(0));
            }

            // format number using legal pattern
            NumberFormat lNumberFormatter = new DecimalFormat(aPattern);
            lFormattedNumber = lNumberFormatter.format(aNumber);

            int lLenghtDifference = lOriginalPattern.length()
                    - lFormattedNumber.length();
            // add illegal chars to formatted string using their indexes
            Enumeration<Integer> lKeys = lIlligalChars.keys();
            while (lKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                Integer lIllegalCharIndex = lKeys.nextElement();
                int lInsertIndex = lIllegalCharIndex.intValue()
                        - lLenghtDifference;
                // insert illegal chars into formatted number
                if (lInsertIndex >= 0
                        || lInsertIndex < lFormattedNumber.length()) {
                    lFormattedNumber = new StringBuffer(lFormattedNumber)
                            .insert(lInsertIndex,
                                    lIlligalChars.get(lIllegalCharIndex)
                                            .charAt(0)).toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          Log.d("info", "formater error:" + e + "mask: " + aPattern
//                  + " number:" + aNumber);
        }

        return lFormattedNumber;
    }

public static String removeChar(String s, char c) {
        StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer(s.length());
        r.setLength(s.length());
        int current = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char cur = s.charAt(i);
            if (cur != c)
                r.setCharAt(current++, cur);
        }
        r.setLength(current);
        return r.toString();
    }
```